# Decide whether the function $f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^4+y}{x^8 + y^2}$ has a limit at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as follows: 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^4+y}{x^8 + y^2}$$
I want to compute the limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^4+y}{x^8 + y^2}$$

This is my attempt..

If $y=x^4$ then,

$$f(x,x^4)= \frac{1}{x^4}$$

Therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: Looks OK to me!

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt could use a little more explanation, but in essence, it is OK.

---

For example, you could explain that you already know that if the limit exists, and because $g: x\mapsto (x,x^4)$ is a continuous function, then the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(g(x))$$ should also exist, but since it does not, this leads to a contradiction.

Or, you could say that you proved that for every $\epsilon>0, M > 0$, there exist some $(x,y)$ such that $\|(x,y)\|\leq \epsilon$ and $f(x,y)>M$, and therefore, $f$ is not bounded on any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and a limit cannot exist.

Comment: If the limit, as (x, y) goes to (0, 0) along a particular path does not exist, or if the limits as (x, y) goes to (0, 0) along two different paths are different, that is sufficient to conclude that the limit itself does not exist.  Note that showing that the limit as (x, y) goes to (0, 0) along one path (or two or three paths and are the same) *does** exist is **not** sufficient to conclude that the limit itself does exist.

Comment: @user247327 Well, the path argument is basically what I wrote in the first part of my answer (using the path $(x,x^4)$).